# Kotlin custom setter

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I'm trying to make a custom property setter for libGDX's sprite.

```
var sprite : Sprite? = null
    get() = sprite
    set(s : String) { sprite = Sprite(Texture(s)) }
```

But it's saying that `s` must be of type `Sprite`, is it possible to do what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should be using [`field`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) instead of `sprite` inside your custom getter/setter. Otherwise recursive calls will be the result.

What you're trying to do does not work, as the compiler tells you. You need to overload the setter and add it as a normal method to your class like this:

```
setSprite(s : String) { sprite = Sprite(Texture(s)) }
```

Comment: very nice that you mention the recursive call. +1

Comment: I was just reading about the field. Well ok then, thanks for the help.

Comment: @WilliMentzel: Thanks, glad you like it ;-)